# How to rewrite sub domain urls on main domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a help with configuring my htaccess. I need to re-write all sub domain urls to main domain.

This is my htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# http => https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# add www to main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# language subdomains handler
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=%1 [QSA,L]
```

I have other re-writed urls like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^about/$ /about.php [NC]
```

This page works fine on main domain.
https://www.example.com/about/

But in sub domain I get 404 error.
https://en.example.com/about/

Can anyone guide me how to fix it ?

PS:
It is another question related to :
[How to configure multiple languages via htaccess and sub domains as a GET method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68243031/how-to-configure-multiple-languages-via-htaccess-and-sub-domains-as-a-get-method/)

Thankyou

Comment: Can you open `https://en.example.com/about.php?lang=en` page in browser and see of that works?

Comment: Yes , It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your full .htaccess like this:

```sh
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

# http => https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# add www to main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# language subdomains handler
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)lang= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=%1 [QSA]

# php extension handler e.g. /about/ => /about.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: yes . the main domain works fine. just sub domain has problem.

Comment: May it be because of sub domain configuration? I created a subdomain in cpanel and pointed to public_html.

Comment: The problem is because of #language subdomains handler part. When I delete it , I can access to https://en.example.com/about/ , but without lang variable.

Comment: Thankyou anubhava for your great help . It works fine now :)